# How do I create and call a basic method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to make a basic method (function) in objective C and am getting some errors, here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self setupWebView];
}

- (void)setupWebView {
    NSLog(@"Testing"); 

}
```

I get this error:

Receiver type 'Reading' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setupWebView'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you declare `-(void)setupWebView` in the header for your class? It seems like the compiler doesn't think that your class implements it. If you add it to your header, it should fix the problem.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to add it to my header file

Answer (score 5):

The compiler will only agree on what the receiver responds to if it has seen the method being declared for the class **above** the source line. So either declare the method in the `@interface` declaration of your class, in some category declaration or implementation for your class.

If you don't want to export `-(void)setupWebView` in your public `@interface`, the easies way is to have class extension of your `@interface` in your `.m` file:

```c
// additional internal methods for my class
@interface MyClass ()

- (void)setupWebView;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self setupWebView];
}

- (void)setupWebView {
    NSLog(@"Testing"); 

}

@end
```